# How to match tag two times in template?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I have xml code:

```
<presentation>

<slide type="title-slide" poradie="1">
  <title>Here is title.</title>
  <autor>Name of autor.</autor>
</slide>

</presentation>
```

And here is my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="/presentation/slide">
  <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('output_new/',@poradie,'.xhtml')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />
  <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xhtml">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <style>
          &css;
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="slide">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="slide[@type = 'title-slide']">
  <div class="container_title_slide">
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h1>
    <h3><xsl:value-of select="autor"/></h3>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

So I want to create XHTML file for each slide. I need to match slide tag two times. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, both your templates match with the same priority, which is considered an error

What you can do is firstly give the first template a higher-priority

```
<xsl:template match="/presentation/slide" priority="2">
```

Then, in your template body, use `<xsl:next-match />` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates/>` which would then apply the template with the lower priorty (Note that `<xsl:apply-templates/>` would be looking for templates that match child nodes, so was not right to use in this case anyway).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"  indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/presentation/slide" priority="2">
      <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat('output_new/',@poradie,'.xhtml')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$filename" />
      <xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="xhtml">
        <html>
          <head>
            <style>
              &amp;css;
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div class="slide">
              <xsl:next-match />
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
      </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="slide[@type = 'title-slide']">
      <div class="container_title_slide">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h1>
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="autor"/></h3>
      </div>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note that I replace `&css;` with `&amp;css;` as `&css;` is not a valid XML entity).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have more slides, so therefore I put there <xsl:apply-templates />. So will it works with other slides too? And you solve me one problem, but another is that when create xhtml there is <div xmln="" class="container_title_slide"> instead of <div class="container_title_slide">. I dont know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You would need to ensure two templates don't match the same `slide` otherwise you might need to start adding more priorities. I have made a tweak to my answer to fix the issue with namespaces.